# Why is my TCL expression returning duplicate results

Tags: regex, scripting, tcl

I'm trying to use TCL to process all of the interfaces on a cisco router. At the moment I'm using the following two commands:

```
set int_out [exec "show interface description"]
```

OUTPUT

```
Interface                      Status         Protocol Description
Fa0/0                          up             up       ** REDACTED **
Fa0/0.209                      up             up       ** REDACTED **
Fa0/0.790                      up             up       ** REDACTED **
Fa0/1                          admin down     down
```

.

```
foreach int [regexp -all -line -inline "^(\[^ ]+)" $int_out] { show clock; puts $int }
```

OUTPUT

```
18:25:16.461 UTC Fri Jun 23 2017Interface

18:25:16.465 UTC Fri Jun 23 2017Interface

18:25:16.469 UTC Fri Jun 23 2017Fa0/0

18:25:16.469 UTC Fri Jun 23 2017Fa0/0

18:25:16.473 UTC Fri Jun 23 2017Fa0/0.209

18:25:16.473 UTC Fri Jun 23 2017Fa0/0.209

18:25:16.477 UTC Fri Jun 23 2017Fa0/0.790

18:25:16.477 UTC Fri Jun 23 2017Fa0/0.790

18:25:16.481 UTC Fri Jun 23 2017Fa0/1

18:25:16.481 UTC Fri Jun 23 2017Fa0/1
```

My goal here is to grab the interface name from each line of output that show interface description produces, and then print it out onscreen. But as you can see, I get duplicates when I go to print the data out on screen. I thought this may have been due to some sort of onscreen logging function at first, but the time stamps that I included in the output seem to indicate otherwise. For example, the first Interface line had a timestamp of 18:25:16.461 while the second one had a timestamp of 18:25:16.465.

What can I do to resolve this issue? I think it may be an issue with my regexp string, which grabs the first word from each line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `regexp -inline` returns a word for the overall match *and* a word for each submatch. Here, let's look at a simple example:

```
puts [regexp -all -inline {.(.).} "abcdef"]
```

This produces this output:

```
abc b def e
```

When you make a sub-RE that matches all non-empty parts of the string that match, as you do in the `^([^ ]+)`, you'll get the whole matched string apparently returned twice.

Your possible fixes are to either change the RE so that it doesn't use capturing parentheses (in your case, you'd be fine with `^[^ ]+`, with any backslashes required to get it through the Tcl parser), or to use the multi-variable form of `foreach` so that you deal with (ignore?) all the matched sub-parts you don't care about:

```
foreach {int inner} [regexp -all -line -inline "^(\[^ ]+)" $int_out] {
    show clock
    puts $int
}
```

(FWIW, you're usually recommended to put REs in `{`braces`}` so as to avoid having o add lots of backslashes. It's not your problem, but it's good style anyway.)

Comment: thanks! that did the trick. good idea with the multi-variable form of foreach too